# How to store reference to (and update/retrieve) object property in javascript array

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, javascript-objects

Here is an object

```
var someObject = {
    value1: 'nothing',
    value2: 'nothing',
    ...
}
```

Here is an array

```
var someArray = [someObject.value1, someObject.value2, ...]
```

Here is a problem

```
forEach(var i in someArray){
    //How would I update someObject.value1 here
    someArray[i] = 'something'
}
//so that this would be 'something'
var someVar = SomeObject.value1
```

Edit: This solution worked for my needs

```
someObject: same

someArray = ['value1', 'value2']

forEach(var i in someArray){
    someObject[someArray[i] = 'something'
}

console.log(someObject.value1) //something
```

Comment: If your `value1` etc are simple strings like this, you can't essentially - you lost the reference to `someObject` when you copied the value to the array.  This smells like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is your end goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `someArray`, you have references to primitive values and not to objects.

You could store the keys of the object `someObject` and use them to update the object.

```js
var someObject = { value1: 'nothing', value2: 'nothing' },
    someArray = ['value1', 'value2'];                      // keys

someArray.forEach(k => someObject[k] = 'something');       // update with keys

console.log(someObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to update on object (someObject) using an array (someArray). If is this the case, you don't have to, because you can loop directly an object:

```
for(key in someObject){
  someObject[key] = 'something'
}
```